# Preview HTML with Jinja2 fields

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, atom-editor

I've just started to develop Flask webapps. I can say I'm new in the field of web developing.
Right now I'm using Atom with some addons, like PreviewHTML to get a side pane and shows a live preview of the HTML.

The problem I'm facing is: if I have an HTML with Jinja2 fields, I can't see a preview of the page I'm coding (it doesn't recognize the statement `{% extends 'base.html' %}` (that *base.html* exists and works fine) and fields are just[image] surrounded by curly brackets).

I was wondering, how do you perform this work properly?

What I do now is prepare an HTML with 100% html tags, and when I see it is fine, I convert these lines to jinja fields (with the classes I need).

Is there any solution to make it easier?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks @chfaber and Stephen for both answers.
I know how to run it and see how does it work. The main problem I am having is when designing the page with those Jinja fields, I can't preview it like a 100% HTML page. I have to make changes and run in Chrome, over and over, can this be speeded up somehow?

Answer (score 0):

That is because the html that you are writing is not pure html. All of those jinja2 tags ({%%}, {{}}, etc) are used at render time which is done by jinja2. What you are seeing is the raw html before it is rendered by jinja2. So to see the rendered html you have to run the app and let it render the html for you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are coding a flask app (thanks to your tags). In which case you will need to run the flask app from the command line in order for the jinja to be recognised.

What you do is run your flask app by:

python filename.py

This will run your app in a browser. So go to your browser and type in http://127.0.0.1:5000/

Then providing you have set up a route for the page that you are after, then you will be able to view the page that you have created.

A flask file for rendering a basic html page 'index.html' would like something like this:

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template

    app = Flask(__name__) 

    @app.route('/')
    @app.route('/index') 
    def index(): 
        return render_template('index.html')

    if __name__ == '__main__': 
        app.run()
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Javinair, Sorry I didn't reply to your comment earlier, I hadn't seen any notifications.  Your jinja fields should be being shown properly in Chrome when you run your app through the command line.  If you are seeking to reload your app when you make changes to your app, there is a way... You need to have your app in development mode (Which will reload your app if you make changes to your python files.  As to the html files, you need to set an environment variable to TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD=True.  This will help the html files reload when you have saved changes to them.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the live html preview that you are using does not work on jinja fields.  You need to run your python file from the command line for that. You can auto reload the html files by setting an environment variable 'TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD=True' for your flask app, while the app is in development mode. Let me know if you need this explained on how to do it.